# As someone living in Portugal, how would I buy a stock listed on a Japanese exchange?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, international-trading, japan

I want to support a gaming company (Square Enix) by buying their stock. From what I've seen, my bank only uses major European and international stock exchanges, and from my searches, Square Enix Holdings is listed on the Tokyo Stock Exchange (TYO).

How can I buy stock in this company? I'm from Portugal.

Comment: Consider whether your proposed investment plan is *wise*. Buying individual stocks, especially fun video game maker stocks, probably isn't the best plan for a beginning investor... and can be expensive. (If you're charged a $10 fee to trade, and put $100 into the market, that's ten percent of your investment gone just to get in, and more to take it out. By the time you invest enough for it to make sense, you're talking about serious money).

Comment: I'm not in it for the money nor to go mad and spend too much, just to get a feeling of what is to deal in stocks and how it works, and i find that investing in something that i enjoy and want to support a good way to wet my feet.

Comment: @GriffinHeart Furthermore, if you simply want to support the company, buying their stock isn't the way to do so. It's expensive for you, and you're not necessarily (in fact, probably not) buying the shares from the *company*. They're not receiving your money; they already received the money for the shares during the IPO. You would be buying the shares from another investor who holds them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Major brokerages may offer an account type for international trading. In the US, E*Trade offers a "Global Trading" account that can be used to hold foreign stocks. You may need to shop around to find a similar offering in Portugal.

Comment: Can i only use Brokerages of my own country? I have no idea of how it works and all the info seems confusing/overwhelming.

Comment: @GriffinHeart Yes, in general it is best to open a brokerage account in your own country.  The good brokerage companies should give you access to overseas markets.  It is difficult to open an account elsewhere - best avoided.

Comment: Brokerages and their customers are best when they're under the same regulatory regime. My brokerage is set up to send me a form 1099-INT for my taxes, but that's not going to help you in Portugal. They (or you) also might run afoul of Portuguese securities laws, which are different than American ones. So most will only operate in one country; a few big ones may have subsidiaries in multiple countries.